# Vue event was emitted, but wasn't received

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a Typescript + Vue app of one parent object and one component (pager):

```
//pager.ts
@Component({
    name: "pager",
    template: require("text!./pager.html")
})
export default class Pager extends Vue {
    onClick(pageIndex: number) : void{
        this.$emit("pageClick", pageIndex);
    }
}

<!-- pager.html -->
<div id="pager" class="text-center" xmlns:v-on="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <a v-on:click="onClick(1)">
        1
    </a>
</div>
```

The parent vue and html file:

```
// main.ts
this.vue = new Vue( {
    el: "#log-container",
    components:{
        pager: Pager
    },
    methods: {
        loadFromServer(pageIndex: number) : void
        {
            // do thing
        }
    },
    created(){
        // it workes
        this.loadFromServer(1);
    }
});

<!-- main.html -->
<div id="log-container">
    <pager v-on:page-click="loadFromServer">
    </pager>
</div>
```

So the problem is I see that the event was emitted successfully, but it wasn't received by the main Vue object and the `loadFromServer` method wasn't called.

Also:

- This method is also called inside `created` and it is called properly
- If I change `v-on:page-click="loadFromServer"` to `v-on:page-click="somethingElse"` I will see the Vue error of method somethingElse doesn't exists. So looks like Vue parse my all stuff properly too.

Despite all of that the loadFromServer *is not called*.

Comment: I've found it best just to avoid camelCase in events altogether. Try emitting `page-click` instead.

Comment: ... and it works. I event couldn't think about that. We should use camel-case in code and kebab case in HTML in Vue, isn't it? The funniest part in it if I use camelCase in all cases it doesn't work.
Thanks!

Comment: The casing logic is covered in [the docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/).

Comment: @Nit, thanks! Looks like I have missed that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Bert the right answer is to use kebab-case in time of event emitting.